# check if the variable contains character a-z or A-Z in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm very new to Groovy and started learning with that.

My requirement is to validate if my input variable contains the character between a-z or A- then I have to remove this particular record.

I tried with

```
personIdExternal.text().contains('a-z')
```

I also tried with

```
personIdExternal.text().matches("[a-zA-Z]")
```

And neither is working.

Can you guys please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if(personIdExternal.text() ==~ /.*[A-Za-z].*/) {
   println 'it matches'
} else { 
    println 'it does not match'
}
```

Comment: Also, if for some reason you don't want to use the `==~` operator, you can do something like `if(personIdExternal.text().matches('.*[A-Za-z].*'))`.

Comment: `/(?i)[a-z]/` would also do

Comment: @injecteer - "`/(?i)[a-z]/` would also do " - I don't think that is correct.  For example, I don't think that will match `"1a1"`.  You are still going to need something like the `.*` in front and back, right?

Comment: I meant case-insesitivity and `=~`

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it worked, possible can you please expain this, i know this is basic , since i'm new to this just asked. Thanks again for your help.